# Changes on FTP to BitBucket as a commit

Tags: git, deployment, ftp, bitbucket

It is possible to commit changes on FTP?

I have subdomain for development and I want to use BitBucket.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to commit changes on FTP?

**No.** Git does not support FTP. There are other protocols but FTP is not one of them

Read about the protocols [***`here`***](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) if you are interested.

- [`Local-Protocol`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol)
- [`The-HTTP-Protocols`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-HTTP-Protocols)
- [`The-SSH-Protocol`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol)
- [`The-Git-Protocol`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new bitbucket tool, Pipelines! Configure a new pipeline file:

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git
      pipelines:
      default:
        - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://server/public_html/
```

Before you commit, create the environment variables $ FTP_USERNAME and $ FTP_PASSWORD in settings -> environment variables.

For the push edit the source code and change the "init" to "push" and commit to replace the file on your shared server.

For more information watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HZhHtZebdw